# Optimize this bit of conduit code for speed

Tags: haskell, optimization

I am implementing an approximate counting algorithm where we:

Maintain t counters {X<sub>*1*</sub>,..., X<sub>*t*</sub>} using log (log *n*) bits for each

- Initialize all counters to 0
- When an item arrives, increase each X<sub>*i*</sub> by 1 independently with probability (½)<sup>X<sub>*i*</sub></sup>
- When the stream is over, output Z =  1/t (2<sup>X<sub>*1*</sub></sup> − 1 + ... + 2<sup>X<sub>*t*</sub></sup> − 1)
- repeat the above steps m times independently and in parallel and output the median.

Here it is in haskell, using the conduit library.

```
import Data.Random
import Data.Conduit
import Data.List
import Data.Ord (comparing)
import qualified Data.Conduit.List as Cl

import Control.Monad.Identity


type Prob    = Double
type Counter = Float
type Delta   = Double
type Eps     = Double


-- * Run Morris alpha on stream inputs `xs`
morrisA :: [a] -> IO Counter
morrisA xs = flip runRVar StdRandom $ Cl.sourceList xs $$ alpha

-- * Run Morris beta on stream inputs `xs` for `t` independent trials and average
morrisB :: Int -> [a] -> IO Counter
morrisB t =  fmap rmean . replicateM t . morrisA

-- * final morris algorithm
-- * Run on stream inputs `xs` for t independent trials for `t = 1/eps`, 
-- * and `m` times in parralell, for `m = 1/(e^2 * d)`
-- * and take the median

morris :: Eps -> Delta -> [a] -> IO Counter
morris e d = fmap rmedian . replicateM m . morrisB t 
  where (t,m) = (round $ 1/(e^2*d), round $ 1/d)

-- * Utils * -- 

-- * A step in morris Algorithm alpha
alpha :: Sink a RVar Counter
alpha = (\x -> 2^(round x) - 1) <$> Cl.foldM (\x _ -> incr x) 0

-- * Increment a counter `x` with probability 1/2^x
incr :: Counter -> RVar Counter
incr x = do
  h <- (\q -> q <= (0.5^(round x) :: Prob)) <$> uniform 0 1
  return $ if h then (seq () succ x) else seq () x

rmean, rmedian :: (Floating a, Ord a, RealFrac a) => [a] -> Float
rmean   = fromIntegral . round . mean
rmedian = fromIntegral . round . median

-- |Numerically stable mean
mean :: Floating a => [a] -> a
mean x = fst $ foldl' (\(!m, !n) x -> (m+(x-m)/(n+1),n+1)) (0,0) x

-- |Median
median :: (Floating a, Ord a) => [a] -> a
median x | odd n  = head  $ drop (n `div` 2) x'
         | even n = mean $ take 2 $ drop i x'
                  where i = (length x' `div` 2) - 1
                        x' = sort x
                        n  = length x
```

The problem is that runtime of `morris` is linear in both length of stream and number of iterations `t*m`. So eg `morrisA` takes about 100μs for 100 items. Now if we want to be 95% confident of 5% error, we have to run `morris` for `n=160000` times.

Could someone suggest how to optimize this code? maybe:

1. implement morris in something other than conduit
2. some faster way to repeat `morrisA` other than `replicateM`.

Comment: The poor performance is likely due to the fact that the implementation of `replicateM` is slow (O(n^2)) so your code is actually running slower than O(t*m). See [here](http://www.haskellforall.com/2013/03/pipes-32-listt-codensity-arrowchoice.html) and [here](http://blog.ezyang.com/2012/01/problem-set-the-codensity-transformation/) for improving the asymptotic performance of certain computations. You do the majority of your work in IO, not with conduit - you should run the conduit at the very last moment. Also some things are suspicious.. like `seq () x` - what is that supposed to do?

Comment: @user2407038 seq is not strictly necessary (haha pun), I just wanted to avoid building up a thunk since I only increment the counter, and never do anything else with it. But I'll definitely read the links you sent me!

Comment: @user2407038 and how would I conduit at the last moment? Since IO has to be on the bottom of the monad transformer stack, it seems like I have to run conduit first ...